# Why the image in my paint app isn't showing on the screen?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

```
select("#loadButton").mouseClicked(function(){
  var file = this.files[0];
  file.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
  loadImage(file.src, img => {
      image(img, 0,0);
  });
});
```

I'm building a paint app using p5.js and I'm trying to upload an image file but it doesn’t show on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup a file input and handler. After that, you need to write the image to the canvas. The following was copied directly from the [p5.js website](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createFileInput):

```
let input;
let img;

function setup() {
  input = createFileInput(handleFile);
  input.position(0, 0);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  if (img) {
    image(img, 0, 0, width, height);
  }
}

function handleFile(file) {
  print(file);
  if (file.type === 'image') {
    img = createImg(file.data, '');
    img.hide();
  } else {
    img = null;
  }
}
```